# Appcelerator Titanium image and ico android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

Appcelerator Titanium code not working

```
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});
```

not appears any images??

Comment: Are you on Windows, by any chance? I think there's a Titanium bug with resolving paths on that OS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Add this code tiapp.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">

    <sdk-version>1.7.5</sdk-version>
    <property name="ti.android.fastdev" type="bool">false</property>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</tar.......
```